# Using timer to move my snakes, but dont want to change the interval

Tags: c#, timer

Form1

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            new GameSetting();
            new GameSetting2();
            GameTimer.Interval = 60;
            GameTimer.Tick += UpdateScreen;
            GameTimer.Start();
            startGame();
        }

       private void UpdateScreen(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (GameSetting.Gameover == true || GameSetting2.Gameover2 == true)
            {
                if (KeyInput.KeyInputs(Keys.Enter))
                {
                    startGame();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (KeyInput.KeyInputs(Keys.Right) && GameSetting.Movment != SnakeMovment.Left)
                {
                    GameSetting.Movment = SnakeMovment.Right;
                }

                else if (KeyInput.KeyInputs(Keys.Left) && GameSetting.Movment != SnakeMovment.Right)
                {
                    GameSetting.Movment = SnakeMovment.Left;
                }

                else if (KeyInput.KeyInputs(Keys.Up) && GameSetting.Movment != SnakeMovment.Down)
                {
                    GameSetting.Movment = SnakeMovment.Up;
                }

                else if (KeyInput.KeyInputs(Keys.Down) && GameSetting.Movment != SnakeMovment.Up)
                {
                    GameSetting.Movment = SnakeMovment.Down;
                }

                PlayerMovment();
            }

     private void PlayerMovment()
    {
        for (int i = SnakeBoddy.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                switch (GameSetting.Movment)
                {
                    case SnakeMovment.Right:
                        SnakeBoddy[i].X++;
                        break;

                    case SnakeMovment.Left:
                        SnakeBoddy[i].X--;
                        break;

                    case SnakeMovment.Up:
                        SnakeBoddy[i].Y--;
                        break;

                    case SnakeMovment.Down:
                        SnakeBoddy[i].Y++;
                        break;
                }
```

GameSetting

```
class GameSetting
    {
        public static int Width { get; set; }
        public static int Height { get; set; }
        public static int SnakeSpeed { get; set; }
        public static int GameScore { get; set; }
        public static int GamePoint { get; set; }
        public static bool Gameover { get; set; }
        public static SnakeMovment Movment { get; set; }

        public GameSetting()
        {
            Height = 16;
            Width = 16;
            Gameover = false;
            SnakeSpeed = 60;
            Movment = SnakeMovment.Down;
            GamePoint = 1;
            GameScore = 0;
        }

    }
```

How would I make it so that the snake speed is `= to SnakeSpeed`. I can do something like `GameTimer.Interval = 360/GameSetting.SnakeSpeed;`but that wouldn't work if I have more than 1 snake + I feel like changing the interval is not the right way, and instead of setting the speed of snake to the interval how would i set it to the snake individually?

Comment: Please provide more details on what you are trying to do. Also, are your snakes moving discretely, 1 cell at a time? What does snake speed mean - the count of cells a snake should move in 1 second?

Comment: yeah something like that I want to be able to change how fast the snakes moves and the speed of the snake should be  determined by `SnakeSpeed`